# Is it possible that photons are actually travelling along electromagnetic waves?

Tags: visible-light, electromagnetic-radiation, photons, speed-of-light

They would be like hitch hikers with no mass, a particle en mass a wave, the frequency of which would correspond to within the colour spectrum frequency. Then their motion is due to quantum wave energy.

Comment: Wild ideas don't really work in physics, unless you can formulate them as mathematical equations. Once you have the formal math, you go back and think the other way, such as what this math can mean physically. This is called "interpretation".  Because you offer no new math, your idea can only be viewed as a new interpretation of the quantum fields theory. Can it be? No, sorry, there's just no way to squeeze massless "hitch hikers"  into quantum waves :)

Answer (score 1):

The photon is more properly a feature of [quantum field theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_field_theory), as normal quantum mechanics is not great about dealing with particle creation and destruction.

The mechanism by which quantum mechanics furnishes both classical dynamics and some sort of unobservable wave guiding a wholly-determined classical world in ways that are decidedly nonclassical, is known as the [de Broglie-Bohm pilot wave theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Broglie%E2%80%93Bohm_theory).

Pilot waves have unfortunately for the most part played "catch up" to other interpretations of quantum mechanics, and so the question of a QFT/pilot-wave hybrid is not an obvious "aha, here's what to do!" conclusion by any means. A 2011 review of some approaches is [available on arXiv](https://arxiv.org/abs/1101.5819) if you're interested.

Comment: "Catch up" is an overly nice way to describe a nostalgia for determinism using the concepts cumbersome enough for self deception. The pilot wave theory produces the same results as the non-deterministic quantum mechanics and thus does not remove non-determinism, just relocates it elsewhere to hide under different names like in the witness protection program ;)